# ProgressDialog и динамически созданная кнопка

Tags: java, android, button

Идет процесс загрузки файла, все отображается в ProgressDialog (который нельзя закрыть). У ProgressDialog есть метод setButton, который задает кнопку у ProgressDialog. Как повесить на эту кнопку событие, которое ничего не будет делать, а в конце загрузки повесить событие с закрытием этого ProgressDialog?

Comment: "необходимо отобразить кнопку ОК и повесить на него событие с закрытием" что вы под этим имеете в виду совершенно непонятно. Попробуйте шире раскрыть что же вам нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем сделал так:

```
pDialog = new ProgressDialog(parent);
pDialog.setTitle(parent.getString(R.string.download_please_wait));
pDialog.setMessage("");
pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
pDialog.setMax(MAX_PROGRESS);
pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
pDialog.setCancelable(false);
pDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
pDialog.setButton(Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Пожалуйста, подождите...", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
});
pDialog.show();
pDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setClickable(false);

// my download code

pDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setText("Закрыть");
pDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setClickable(true);
```